# How to publish my rails app into github pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll, github-pages

Hello I'm trying to find a way to deploy my Rails app into GitHub but so far i have read that GitHub can only host static sites. So i started looking for Jekyll but here is my problem: I already have an existing rails app how can i deploy it without starting it from scratch cause I don't know how to use the Jekyll gem.

So is there a way to deploy my Rails app without creating again?

Comment: Using **BOLD** like this is actually quite annoying. Please don't.

Comment: The defining question here is does your Rails app do anything other than display static pages. If it has dynamic content and a database, GitHub pages can't do it. If it's just a bunch of static views, it could.

Comment: No it hasn't its a portfolio that i want to upload.I don't have any form that need database.

Comment: It should be possible to convert it over if you haven't made anything dynamic yet.

Comment: How i can accomplish that?

Comment: Step 1: [Read up on Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com). Step 2: Give it a shot. The learning curve isn't that bad, and for a basic site you can probably get something up and running in a few hours. Liquid, the template used by Jekyll, is pretty straight-forward, especially if you've ever used Handlebars or even ERB.

Comment: I will try to read about jekyll more and if i have any question i will post here

Answer (score 1):

### Cannot use Github Pages To Host Rails App - must use Heroku etc.

Jekyll is good because it is "basically" a static site...........the ruby code there is minimal. But a rails app with a database and logins etc: no you will need to host that on [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/login) (which basically uses Amazon Web Services), or Digital Ocean, or use Amazon Webservices (but you'll have to do all the set up yourself) or you can otherwise host it yourself on your PC.

Github pages, as far as I understand, will not host your rails app.

### Can I convert my rails app into a jekyll app?

That depends. Does your rails app make database calls? Does it have back ground jobs running? If so then, there's no easy way to convert it to a static website. i.e. it's impossible. IT's far cheaper and easier to use heroku. It would be like trying to retro-fit a jumbo jet to run like a car down the highway.

If you rails app simply has a series of pages "posts" which are static then you can easily convert it. You'll have to simply put them in the "posts" directory of your Jekyll set up, with the appropriate names, and then push to Github, and you'll have a nice website running.

### Subscriptions

If you want to use Github pages to host and you want to make your repository private, then you need to subscribe to Github and pay their subscription fees.

As of the time of writing, while private repos are free, if you want to HOST a private repo on Github pages, you'll have to pay the subscription.

Comment: So how can i use jekyll now to create the exact same website that i have create with rails?

Comment: GitHub no longer [charges for private repositories](https://github.com/pricing) for personal accounts.

Comment: My rails app is a portfolio website and its 1 page nothing more. I just want to upload it.So is it viable to do it with jekyll and if yes how can I do it?

Comment: Yes it's very viable and much simpler than a rails app!! For that you'll have to download some themes/styles and copy paste the relevant html to make it work with jekyll.

Comment: I'm using https://startbootstrap.com/themes/creative/ this bootstrap theme, so can you clarify the steps that i must proceed to accomplish that? It really confuses me how to make it work.

Comment: start with a minimal jekyll app, then go for a jekyll based theme. https://jekyllrb.com/docs/ ...........the steps are all actually listed online, it shouldn't be too difficult to get it up and running

Comment: Yeah but with this I will create a new app, am I right?

Comment: it's a new app, but because it's static, you'll have to do a little copy pasting and styling. shouldn't be too difficult